# Is it possible to resize the movie display area in wx.MediaCtrl (Python 2.6)?

Tags: wxpython

I am quite new to Python GUI programming. As a part of an assignmnet I have implemented a simple frame with a media player (wx.MediaCtrl) embeded in it. Now I would like to know if it is possible to resize the display area of MediaCtrl (with out resizing the frame) by pulling it with the mouse or just by hitting a button?

Please help me with this,
Thanks In Advance,
Rajesh.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you exactly want, because If you have put wx.MediaCtrl inside the frame properly using sizer, it should fit the Frame, so how can then you resize it without resizing the frame, alternative is to resize media cntrl manually by setting size e.g.

```
cntrl.SetSize((300,400))
```

and on button do

```
cntrl.SetSize((400,600))
```

It will work if you have manually places the cntrl on frame.

May be you can copy-paste a simple example and ask what exactly you need?